# Basic string compression implementation in C

Tags: c, strings, compression

I tried to implement a string compression algorithm that is mentioned in CTCI-5th 1.5 using C.

- Does this code follow common best practices?
- Performance and correctness in unanticipated cases of this code

```
// Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts
// of repeated characters. For example, the string aabcccccaaa would become
// a2blc5a3. If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original
// string, your method should return the original string.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int countCompression(char* str) {
    if (!str || str == "")
        return 0;

    unsigned int result = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char last = *str;
    unsigned int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (*(str+i) == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            result += 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", count);
            last = *(str+i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    result += 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", count);

    return result;
}

unsigned int concatDigit2Str(char* str, unsigned int digit) {
    unsigned int digit_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", digit);
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);

    sprintf(temp, "%d", digit);

    for (int k = 0; k < digit_len; k++) {
        *(str+k) = temp[k];
    }

    free(temp);
    return digit_len;
}

char* compressString(char* str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (countCompression(str) >= len)
        return str;

    char* result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
    char* result_ptr = result;
    char last = *str;
    unsigned int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (*(str+i) == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            *(result_ptr++) = last;
            result_ptr += concatDigit2Str(result_ptr, count);
            last = *(str+i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    *(result_ptr++) = last;
    result_ptr += concatDigit2Str(result_ptr, count);
    *result_ptr = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* str = "aabcccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    printf("%s\n", str);

    char* new_str = compressString(str);
    printf("%s\n", new_str);

    free(new_str);
    return 0;
}
```

This code and updates are available at: [Github](https://github.com/eckucukoglu/coding-practices/blob/master/ctci-5th/c1-arrays-and-strings/5.c).

Comment: Your code *crashes* in my test for an empty string "" or a single-character string "a". The reason is that `new_str = compressString(str)` can return the original string `str`, in which case `free(new_str)` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: Actually, first of all I tried to post a link to an external site (github) that includes improvements; however the question has put on hold. Editors' stated that "...After the question has been edited to contain working code, we will consider reopening it." So that, even though the updated external link is included in the post, I edited my post. I do not know what should I do, i guess posting a new question is the best option. BTW, answers had already given, and I had already changed my code when the question has put on old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Design

#### Memory Allocation

A string function can either allocate a new string and return it or return a modified version of the original.

Your function **CAN NOT** do both of these. This is because we don't know if the returned string is returned with ownership or not (ownership defines who releases the memory).

1. If your function allocates a new string and returns it then it is returning ownership and thus it is your responsibility to call `free()` on the result at some point.
2. If your function returns the original string (or a pointer to some part of the original string). Then you are **NOT** returning ownership and thus the user should **NEVER** call `free()` on the result.

Unfortunately C does not have a good naming convention to follow on the subject so you can't tell without reading the manual which does what. But you can definitely have two versions of the function.

For example you could have written:

```
char* compressString(char*);   // Compresses String in place.
                               // If compression does not help no change.

char* strCompressString(char*);// Allocates a new string and compresses
                               // the parameter into this new string.
                               // If compression does not help the new
                               // string is the same as the original
                               // Note value returned from this should be freed
```

#### Error In DeCompression

Compression works as long as there are no numbers in your input string.

```
 "aaaaa1" would compress as "a511"
```

If you try uncompressing that you will get a different result. You either need to explicitly check there are no numbers or you need to add a delimiter between your value and your data.

#### Why is the size human readable?

Making the size a human readable number is very limiting and does not help in your compression. You could store the size as an integer value (encoded as a unsigned character).

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"  => "a16"    // Current method  3 characters.
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"  => "a\x10"  // As a number 2 characters.
```

This way also does not suffer from the number limitation. But adds the limitation of only compressing ranges upto `UCHAR_MAX` characters at a time.

### Code Review

This seems like an expensive way of counting the number of characters needed for a number.

```
result += 1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", count);
```

I would have gone with:

```
result += (1 + log10(cont));
```

Here the malloc os cast to `(char*)` this is not required.

```
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);
```

The function `malloc()` returns a `void*`. This can be assigned to any pointer type in `C`. Thus removing the need for a cast operation (which will cause any good linters/style checkers to go apoplectic).

We should also note the size calculations here:

```
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);
```

The expression `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. There is an argument for removing this from the expression. Though I personally prefer to leave it in place (but for me that comes from writing templated functions in C++). Where the type may be changed at some point in the future. So I am OK with leaving it but others may complain.

But the expression is also wrong (not multiplication happens before addition). So really this should be `sizeof(char) * (digit_len + 1)`. If you are implying that the size of object can change at sometime in the future (by using the `sizeof(char)`) then you need to multiply this by the (len + 1) otherwise you have len objects plus a single byte. Which is not logically what you want. You want (len + 1) objects.

Here you allocate memory but don;t check for success.

```
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);
    // this can quite easily be NULL
```

Here you allocate memory for a buffer that is free'd at the end of the function.

```
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);
    // STUFF
    free(temp);
```

Dynamic allocation is relatively expensive (compared with local arrays). And you know the maximum value that a number can be. So you could just have a local buffer (you can even make it way oversized without much cost).

```
    char temp[100];  // Large enough for even 64 bit numbers.
    // No dynamic allocation and no overflow.
    // No chance of failure to allocate.
```

Here you are printing a number into a string:

```
    unsigned int digit_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", digit);
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * digit_len + 1);

    sprintf(temp, "%d", digit);
```

That you then copy into another string.

```
    for (int k = 0; k < digit_len; k++) {
        *(str+k) = temp[k];
    }
```

This seems a bit redundant. When you could use the function to print directly into the destination string.

```
    sprintf(str+k, "%d", digit);
```

Failure to check that the `malloc()` worked.

```
    char* result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);
```

Comment: `log10(count)` and  `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", count)` return different results for inputs like 0,10,100. Moreover, `sprintf(str, "%d", digit);` adds '\0' at the end of the source; if compression is intended to be done in place, then this unexpected change can raise an error.

Comment: `s/255/UCHAR_MAX/`?  (I'm assuming you meant "(encoded as an unsigned char)", else that would be `CHAR_MAX`).  Perhaps also worth a recommendation against casting the return value of `malloc()` in C and/or a note that `sizeof (char) *` is redundant?

Comment: @EmreCanKucukoglu: That's why we have unit tests.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I know `sizeof(char)` is redundant in C++ but was not 100% sure about `C`. I though you **had** to cast the return of `malloc()`.

Comment: @Loki - the return value of malloc is `void*` as you know - in C++ it needs a cast, but in C a `void*` value can be assigned to _any kind_ of pointer variable.  In both languages, _any_ pointer can be assigned to a `void*` variable.  And in both languages, the `sizeof` operator returns values in units of `char` - it looks like you misremember which of those differs between the two languages and which is the same.  It's a bit like Mark Twain said about Britain and America: two nations separated by a common language!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `*(str+i)`, you should write the idiomatic `str[i]`.

In names, do not use the number `2` when you mean the word `to`.

Don't use `sprintf` and `snprintf` together. Always stick to `snprintf`, to prevent buffer overflows by carelessness.

To test your code properly, you need more than one example string. For each of these example strings, run the following code:

```
char *roundtrip = decompressString(compressString(str));
```

The `roundtrip` must always equal the original string. By extension, this means:

```
char *roundtrip = decompressString(decompressString(
    compressString(compressString(str))));
```

This must also work.

I wouldn't be surprised if that book, when using the term *character*, means ASCII-encoded letter from `a` to `z`, which is impractical for real-life tasks. So take all examples from that book with a grain of salt. And don't trust the official solutions, they are often wrong.

A general rule is that compression algorithms must be able to handle *any* input and still produce reasonable results. Therefore your code should be able to compress and decompress strings of arbitrary characters, not just `a-z`.